# Load Balancing across all ports

Tags: apache, load-balancing, haproxy

I'm looking to add a load balancer in front of a service that might be listening on any port. I've looked at a few options (apache, haproxy) but they seem to all work by specific ports -- e.g.

```
example.com:80
    server1:80
```

What I need:

```
example.com:N
    server1:N
    server2:N
```

Where N can be any port. In otherwords, basically round robin dns, but with failover support.

Ideas about how this can be done on mod_proxy_balancer, haproxy or any other freely avaliable lb? Thanks.

Comment: That sounds a little odd. I've not seen software that will bind to every port with a wildcard and I'd guess you would have issues trying to make something do it.  Do you really need the front end to listen on all ports as well?  Can the backend notify the front end of the port somehow?

Comment: That is a possibility, but would be very messy. I guess that a better way to think about this might be round robin dns distribution that supports failover.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by the comparison. Round robin DNS has nothing to do with TCP ports.  Do you mean like round robin DNS but with ports instead of the DNS?

Comment: I actually think I found my answer -- http://serverfault.com/questions/577103/how-to-configure-haproxy-to-route-by-port-without-using-multiple-frontend-or-lis

However, thanks for your time!